# Pass variable from one component to another

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-props

I am making this travel review site. I want to fetch the correct collection from Firebase when I am browsing one of the continent components.

It works if I hardcode a continent like this:

```
const useCountries = (props) => {
    this.cont = "";
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("Africa")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const newCountries = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                }))
                setCountries(newCountries)
            })
    }, [])
    return countries
}



const CountryList = ({ displayFields = [] }) => {
    const countries = useCountries();

    return (
        <div className="countries">
            {countries.map(country => (
                <div key={country.id}>
                    <div className="entry">

                        {displayFields.includes("continent") && (
                            <div>Name of continent: {country.continent}</div>

                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("revName") && (
                            <div>{country.revName}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("countryName") && (
                            <div><Link to={"./Jumbotron"}>{country.countryName}</Link></div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("dest1") && (
                            <div>Destination 1: {country.dest1}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("dest2") && (
                            <div>Destination 2: {country.dest2}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("dest3") && (
                            <div>Destination 3: {country.dest3}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("beerPrice") && (
                            <div>Beer price: {country.beerPrice}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("foodPrice") && (
                            <div>Food price: {country.foodPrice}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("hostelPrice") && (
                            <div>Hostel price: {country.hostelPrice}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("review") && <div>Review: {country.review}</div>}
                        {displayFields.includes("imgUrl") && <img src={country.url} alt="no-img" />}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default CountryList
```

However, as I stated, I want to be able to fetch the correct data.

What I want, is to pass the value of the continent.

This sidebar understands in which continent I am:

```
const VerContinentToolbar = (props) => {


    return (
      <Menu className="nav-icon">
        <CountryList displayFields={["countryName"]} />
      </Menu>
    );

};
```

What I want to do is to send the information in VerContinentBar to the country-list, use the value as a variable and use the variable in the collection like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(VARIABLE)
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const newCountries = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                }))
                setCountries(newCountries)

            })


    }, [])
    return countries
}
```

Needless to say, I am very new to React. I have no idea how to accomplish this. I've been stuck here all day.

I know that this is no beauty.

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to delete your question there is a 'delete' link just below the question text.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) that sits above your components.

On the Context you can declare a property for `continent` and update it from the component that is responsible for this.

All components should treat this context as the source of truth.